# How do I make xunit stop the jenkins pipeline on fail?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, xunit

[This guy seems to have the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41423745/should-i-use-xunitpublisher-or-xunitbuilder-after-building-xunit-xml-files).

Here is what I am doing:

```
    stage('Test') {
        steps {
            bat "\"${tool 'VSTestRunner'}\" %WORKSPACE%\\MyApp\\bin\\Debug\\MyApp.dll /logger:trx & exit 0"
            // The test publish is responsible for decided whether the test stage failed
            step([$class : 'XUnitPublisher',
                testTimeMargin: '3000',
                thresholdMode: 1,
                thresholds: [
                    [$class: 'FailedThreshold', failureNewThreshold: '', failureThreshold: '1', unstableNewThreshold: '', unstableThreshold: ''],
                    [$class: 'SkippedThreshold', failureNewThreshold: '', failureThreshold: '', unstableNewThreshold: '', unstableThreshold: '']
                ],
                tools : [[$class: 'MSTestJunitHudsonTestType',
                    deleteOutputFiles: true,
                    failIfNotNew: false,
                    pattern: "TestResults\\*.trx",
                    skipNoTestFiles: false,
                    stopProcessingIfError: true
                ]]
            ])

        }
    }
```

If the tests fail the pipeline still continues.

I would like to be able to control whether the pipeline continues or not via the xunit settings. Is there a more elegant way of doing this than this:

```
if (currentBuild.result.equals("FAILURE")) {
    throw "Test results did not pass thresholds"
}
```

Also, what does "stopProcessingIfError" do? I thought it would stop the pipeline if the error threshold was exceeded but it doesn't. Is there a param to the xunit service that does that?

Comment: Generally if you want to fail a build, you have to throw an exit status != 0

Comment: What error levels do I have available to me? just FAILED, SUCCESS, and UNSTABLE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FAILED, SUCCESS, and UNSTABLE are jenkins build status and not exit status. exit status should come from the process that is being executed. So, your solution is to set an `exit 1` (or something non-zero), if the test fails. You batch step seem to be setting an exit 0. Check for the ERRORLEVEL as you seem to be in windows, and if its non-zero, break out from the pipeline by forcing an `exit 1'

note: it can be anything but should not be 0. (i am referring to the 1 in exit code)

Comment: this makes more sense to me. xunit is setting the build status correctly and the process is exiting without errors so it "succeeded" then at that point its up to me to read the build status and decide if I want the pipeline to fail.